# Skip the first item while iteration through List

Tags: java

I need to skip the very first item iterating through the `List`.

```
for (MyClass myObject : myList) {
    myObject.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: use a boolean declared outside the loop ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Something like:

```
for (MyClass myObject : myList.subList(1, myList.size()) {
       myObject.doSomething();
}
```

though I think it might not work if your list doesn't have at least one item...

Answer (score 11):

If you use a regular for loop you can do it like this:

```
int size = myList.size();
for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
    myList.get(i).doSomething();
}
```

or inline:

```
for (int i = 1; i < myList.size(); i++) {
    myList.get(i).doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Surely this answer is pretty clear in intent, and is preferable to the `subList` one because it won't throw an Exception when `myList` is empty!

Comment: Won't this call `myList.size()` once for every loop?

Comment: @Joe Yeah it will, so you'd just define an int prior to the loop (for example, int x = myList.size()) then have i < x.

Comment: I'd update it if I were you. As it stands it's not a great answer.

Comment: @Joe: Just curious - given that `List.size()` for the majority of implementations just retrieves the size from a private instance field of the list class, and thus very definitely runs in constant time, do you think the drawback of the performance overhead of method dispatch outweighed the benefit of the clarity conveyed in Jack's original code fragment?

Comment: Well it depends what you're dealing with. If it's actually a `List` then it'll probably be quite efficient. The `List` implementation is likely designed for this kind of use. But if it's an `IList` or an `ICollection`, it could be implemented in any number of ways, expensive or cheap, and given that the collection classes are mutable, the compiler knows that it has to be re-evaluated each time. I suppose it doesn't really matter for small uses, but something to watch out for. I only thought about it because it's normal to use an `IEnumerator` for iterating over `ICollections`.

Comment: Before getting excited about the `size()`: The `get(i)` has _much_ more performance impact in case of a `LinkedList`.

Comment: I agree about the get(i) on LinkedList. But if you use an Arraylist then definelty second method supports the empty list while first one doesn't.

Answer (score 6):

For completeness, an Iterator example:

```
    Iterator<MyClass> iterator = myList.iterator();
    if (iterator.hasNext()) {
        iterator.next();
    }

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        iterator.next().doSomething();
    }
```